# How does the md5 hashing algorithm compress data to a fixed length?

Tags: algorithm, compression, md5, bit

I know that MD5 produces a 128-bit digest. My question is, how does it produce this fixed length output from a message of 128bits+?

**EDIT:**

I have now a greater understanding of hashing functions now. After reading [this article](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-crypto-hashes.html) I have realized that hash functions are one-way, meaning that you can't convert the hash back to plaintext. I was under the misimpression that you could due to all the online services converting them back to strings, but I have realised that thats just rainbow tables (collections of string's mapped to pre-computed hashes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you generate an [MD5 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), you're not compressing the input data. Compression implies that you'll be able to uncompress it back to it's original state. MD5, on the other hand, is a one-way process. This is why it's used for password storage; you ideally have to know the original input string to be able to generate the same MD5 result again.

This page provides a nice graphic-equipped explanation of MD5 and similar hash functions, and how they're used: [An Illustrated Guide to Cryptographic Hashes](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-crypto-hashes.html)

Comment: Well, hopefully one *doesn't* use MD5 for passwords (or at all as there are a number of alternative/better options these days), but the general idea is the same +1 ;-)

Comment: The term [compression](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/One-way_compression_function) is used in describing cryptographic hash functions, but it means something different than the usual Zip/Bzip/7Zip meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Consider something like starting with a 128-bit value, and taking input 128 bits at a time, and XORing each of those input blocks with the existing value.

MD5 is considerably more complex than that, but the general idea is the same: input is processed 128 bits at a time. Each input block can change the value of the result, but has no effect on the length.

Comment: But what if the message is larger than the maximum hash digest size (128 bits for MD5)? What does it do then?

Comment: The algorithm splits the message into chunks, and then mixes each chunk into the hash one-by-one. The whole message contributes to the final value of the hash, but the algorithm only looks at one chunk at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It has noting (or, better, few) to do with compression. There is an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm) which produces for every initial state and byte a new state. This state is more or less unique to this combination of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it will split into many parts and do operation.

If you are wonder about the collsion, consider your message is only Readable.

The bit space is much bigger than readable char space.